# Set up a e-mailing module in python-django project, so that any e-mail throughout the project can use the module

Tags: django, email

**How to set up a e-mailing module in python-django project, so that throughout the project emails can be triggered without blocking the request.**

Answer (score 0):

Use stuff like celery tasks to execute mail sending or outside API's like Sparkpost which accept the task and do not block executing